# Getting error " Value of type 'Label' cannot be converted to 'Label' "

Tags: vb.net

I don't know why I get this error sometimes and not for every time I try to build an array of labels. The code examples are in different forms in the same project.

The following code is fine, no error messages.

```
Private Sub SetLabelColor(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label4.Click, Label3.Click,
    Label19.Click, Label20.Click

    Dim lb() As Label = {Label4, Label3, Label19, Label20}

    If sender Is Label4 Then
        'MsgBox("4")
        lb(0).BackColor = Color.AliceBlue
    ElseIf sender Is Label3 Then
        lb(1).BackColor = Color.Bisque
    ElseIf sender Is Label19 Then
        lb(2).BackColor = Color.Gainsboro
    ElseIf sender Is Label20 Then
        lb(3).BackColor = Color.LemonChiffon
    End If

End Sub
```

However, the following code give me the error on the 2 labels in the DIM statement:

```
Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click, Label1.Click
    
    Dim lb() As Label = {Label2, Label1}
    If sender Is Label1 Then
        'do something
    End If

End Sub
```

I am completely at a loss as to the reason why. HELP!!!

I've moved the code giving me the error to different subs and I get the same error.

Comment: Are you sure that label1 or exist and are labels? Also it would be best to give the labels a better name the label1 to 128

Comment: What [`Imports` statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/imports-statement-net-namespace-and-type) do you have in the file with `Label1,Label2`? Maybe you reference a `Label` which is not the [`System.Windows.Forms.Label`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). There are more with that name, for example [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.label?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) or [this](https://shorturl.at/nCQX9).

Comment: OT: That code is rather silly in what it does. the whole point of using a single method to handle multiple events is because you do the same thing in each case but you are explicitly not doing the same thing. If you have to check whether the `sender` is a specific object then you should have a dedicated event handler for that object. That first code snippet should be replaced with four separate event handlers, each with one line of code, e.g. `Label4.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue`.

Comment: Cont... As it is, your array is pointless because you're already referencing the specific `Label` in the `If` statement itself so you may as well in the `If` block too. If you really want to use a single event handler then you should actually make use of the array. That would mean creating an array of `Color` values too. You could then use `Array.IndexOf` to get the index of the `sender` in the `Label` array and use that to get the correct `Color` from the other array, then assign that `Color` to the `BackColor` property of the `sender`. That makes sense for a single event handler.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a WinForms project, as it appears to be, and you added standard WinForms `Label` controls to your form in the designer, as opposed to your own custom control or a third-party control, then `Label1` and `Label2` must refer to `System.Windows.Forms.Label` controls. Unless something is corrupt in VS, that means when you declare your `lb` variable as type `Label`, it must be being interpreted as a different type. The only way I can see that happening is if you have imported a namespace at the top of the code file that has a member named `Label`, e.g.

```vb
Imports System.Windows.Controls
```

That is the namespace for WPF controls, so it shouldn't be there to begin with. Get rid of whatever namespace you have imported if you can. If you have imported some other namespace that you actually do need then you can fully-qualify the type in your code:

```vb
Dim lb() As System.Windows.Forms.Label = {Label2, Label1}
```

Of course, if you have `Option Infer On`, which it is by default, then you don't need to specify a type at all. If you assign a `Label` array to the variable when you declare it then it will be inferred to be that type:

```vb
Dim labels = {Label2, Label1}
```

Notice that I have also taken the liberty of changing the name of the variable to something sensible. Variables should generally be descriptive of what they are and array or collection variables should generally have pluralised names.

Your code makes little sense as it is though. The point of using a single method to handle multiple events is so you can do exactly the same thing in all cases. Based on your first code snippet, you are doing something different in all cases so you ought to have separate event handlers. Your code should be this:

```vb
Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click    
    'Do something to Label1
End Sub

Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click    
    'Do something to Label2
End Sub
```

Based on your first code snippet, you could make using a single method make sense like this:

```vb
Private Sub SetLabelBackColor(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label4.Click,
                                                                        Label3.Click,
                                                                        Label19.Click,
                                                                        Label20.Click
    Dim labels = {Label4, Label3, Label19, Label20}
    Dim colours = {Color.AliceBlue, Color.Bisque, Color.Gainsboro, Color.LemonChiffon}
    Dim label = DirectCast(sender, Label)
    Dim index = Array.IndexOf(labels, label)
    Dim colour = colours(index)

    label.BackColor = colour
End Sub
```

Notice that there is no code there that is specific to any `Label`.